# How can I make an Atlas of the land cover within each of the watersheds?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, qgis-2.8, atlas, layer-file

I have a Land Cover raster that has its legend in a layer-file (.lyr), and a shapefile delineating watersheds. I have access to QGIS 2.8.1 and to ArcGIS 10.1.

I want an Atlas of the land cover within each of the watersheds.

Since I only know how to open a Layer-file (.lyr) in ArcGIS, and I only know how to make an Atlas in QGIS, How can I make an Atlas of the land cover within each of the watersheds?

Comment: QGIS Atlas = ArcGIS [Data Driven Pages](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_are_Data_Driven_Pages/00s90000003m000000/) (DDP). It's very quick and easy to learn. Alternatively, if you can't directly convert the lyr file to sld, depending on how many classes there are (or even classes in that specific raster) maybe you just recreate the style in QGIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up converting my raster Land Cover layer in Shapefile and using the Atlas in QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

Your question mainly pertains to converting a lyr to qgis readable format. The only way that you can achieve this is by using ArcMap2sld which convert the style to sld which is ogc compliant which qgis can read and understand.

Comment: ArcMap2sld doesn't work on my computer.
I downloaded the ArcMap2sld 1.3.0.
I have Windows 7 (64 bits) and ArcMap 10.1.

In the "readme_english" file, it says : "The ArcGIS-map to SLD Converter version 1.3.0 was developed for ArcMap 10. It works on Windows XP and Windows 7." So I don't know why it doesn't work... 

Any help?